# How can I get the row number after the latest condition in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table named product. Here is the the table structure:

```
id name    date         status
1   A    2018-8-10        z
2   A    2018-8-11        x
3   A    2018-8-12        z
4   A    2018-8-13        z
5   A    2018-8-14        x   <- After this, last status = x
6   A    2018-8-15        z
7   A    2018-8-16        z
8   A    2018-8-17        z
```

Now, I want the row number when status = x after the last x that means 3 rows.

Comment: Whit row number, do you mean the id?

Comment: No, I have to count row number just.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by write two query as the following:

```
 $result = modelName::latest('date')->where('status','x')->first();
 $row_count = modelName::where('date','>',$result->date)->count();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a normal query you can do this something like this. So find the last entry that hast the status `x`. Then select all that is bigger then this id. Then you should have all remaining entries.

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.id > (SELECT id FROM table WHERE status = 'x' LIMIT 1 ORDER BY id DESC)
```

I'm not so good in Laravel but you can try something lie this:

```
$result = myModel::latest('id')->where('status','x')->first();
$row_count = myModel::where('id','>',$result->id)->count();
```